# How to get pictures from google picture search page in Android

Tags: android, webview

I need to implement component that shows list of pictures related to given search query. Pictures are loading from google picture search.
What can I use instead of google picture search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example on Github:

https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion-sample/src/com/koushikdutta/ion/sample/GoogleImageSearch.java

Answer (score 2):

1. Parse json from
   https://developers.google.com/image-search/?hl=ru (deprecated and limited)
   https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview (free but with limitations)
2. Run search query in hidden WebView and get list
   of images after page loading.

   enter code here
   query = "https://www.google.com.ua/search?safe=on&site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=milk+buy";

web = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web);
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }

        // you tell the webclient you want to catch when a url is about to
        // load
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        // here you get all links to pictures
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i("web link", String.format(url));
            if (url.compareTo(query) != 0) {
                images.add(url);
            }
        }
    });

    web.loadUrl(query);
```

Comment: Is this breaking any licenses, rules or standards? And is there a better way to do that nowadays?